# Django - passing parameters to GET method when using JS window.open() function

Tags: javascript, django

I Have the following JS script which opens a new window and renders a Django template corresponding to `/my_url/`.

```
function draw_comparing_graphs()
{
    window.open('/my_url/', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=1500,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');  
}
```

Now, the question is, how do I pass on parameters to Django ? I mean, what is the equivalent of `$.post('/my_url/', data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just opening a page, using `POST` is not an easy option (you could by having it automatically submit a form from `/my_url/`, but I wouldn't recommend it). You could easily append some `GET` parameters to `/my_url/` though. Something like: `/my_url/?json=...your-json-data...

Within Django you can reach this using `request.GET['json']`

Example with your code:

```
function draw_comparing_graphs()
{
    window.open('/my_url/?json=' + encodeURIComponent(json_data), '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=1500,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');  
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention one detail. The passing parameter is a JSON object

Comment: In that case you can simply urlencode it and pass it along: `encodeURIComponent(json_string)` and within Django you can use `import json; data = json.loads(json_string)`

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly this `encodeURIComponent(json_string)` fits into the code ?

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan I've updated the example. If the object isn't in json format yet you have to wrap it in a `JSON.stringify(data)` call